# Abbreviation for supervisor

Tags: abbreviations

The simple version of my question would be: "What is the abbreviation of 'Supervisor'"?

However, I will add some explaining. I am abbreviating the word "operator" as "Op" already (size constraints) so would it be understandable if I abbreviate supervisor as "Sv"?

Comment: What are the abbreviations being used for, and will there be a reference to the actual word anywhere? On its own, `Sv` is not an abbreviation for supervisor, but if you provide a context, and make it clear, then you can use practically any abbreviation, within a limited target audience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In isolation Sv would not be understood, it could mean server or serviceman or savant ...

In context, especially if you have used the full word once, or better still defined your abbreviation you will be understood.

> When the store opens the Supervisor (Sv.) must ensure ... The Sv. must then ...